# PL/SQL save output from SELECT and display it with PUT_LINE

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have been strugelling with a problem for a while and I can't really figure how to do what I want to do.

Considering the following Cursor, I read all the IDs from my Table, where a column has all the values from a variable. Using this cursor, I identify all the records I want to delete from within the table. So far so good.

Because I will be deleting some rows from within the Database, I would like to first save the affected rows in an INSERT INTO format. For that, I am using the " select / * insert * / * " hint from SQL Developer.

Unfortunately, here comes my problem. I can't find a way to display the result of the SELECT within the SCRIPT Output using DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE. When trying to execute my code as it is, I receive the " PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values " Error Message.

Do you guys know by any chance how I could solve my problem?

My code is:

```
DECLARE CURSOR C2 is 
       select my_id from my_table where my_id in (v_id);
           BEGIN
               for i in C2 LOOP
                   SELECT my_second_id into v_test from my_table where my_id = i.my_id;
                   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('A DELETE has to be performed within my_table, for the following ID: '||v_test);
                   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('                                ');
                   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The Backups are as follows: ');
                   select /*insert*/ * into v_why_does_it_not_work from my_table where my_id = i.my_id;
                   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_why_does_it_not_work);
               END LOOP;
           END;
```

My Output is:

```
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 30, column 70:
PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values
ORA-06550: line 30, column 37:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

And I would like my output to be like:

```
A DELETE has to be performed within my_table, for the following ID: my_second_id
                                
The Backups are as follows: 
Insert into my_table (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6) values (val1,val2,val3,val4,val5,val6);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is obviously wrong:

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The Backups are as follows: '
                   select /*insert*/ * into v_why_does_it_not_work
```

as you haven't terminated the first line; should be

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The Backups are as follows:');
select /*insert*/ * into v_why_does_it_not_work
```

---

As of the error itself, Oracle says it is in line #30, column #70. Code you posted doesn't have 30 lines so I can't tell whether this is wrong or something else.

I'd, though, recommend you to **avoid** `select *` - always specify all columns you're using.

---

OK, typos aside, but - that just won't work. You said you've used a **hint**. Nope, that's just a comment, not a hint.

Also, if you want to create `INSERT INTO` statements, you'll have to do it using dynamic SQL, store its value into a variable and display it (using `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE`).

Alternatively, consider storing old (deleted) values into your own *audit* table. We use database triggers to do that.

Comment: it was a typo ... i forgot copy that row until the end. I have edited my post and wrote the correct statement.
At line 30 I have the select select /*insert*/ * into v_why_does_it_not_work, whereas column 70 is the start of the FROM keyword.

Comment: Unfortunately, it still isn't OK (semi-colon is missing).

Comment: semi-colon is present. Again, it was a typo.

Comment: Yes, I know. Good if you fixed it. I also added some more info into the answer; have a look, please.

Comment: I saw you new comments. The thing is that if i execute that SELECT Statement with the "hint" as a script, it displays my the exact INSERT INTO statement i need:


REM INSERTING into my_table
SET DEFINE OFF;
Insert into my_table (my_id,my_second_id) values ('2433','123456');
Insert into my_table (my_id,my_second_id) values ('5433','123457');
Insert into my_table (my_id,my_second_id) values ('9433','123460');

Comment: Right; it works in a script, but won't work here. As I said: dynamic SQL or audit. Or, wait a little bit longer, someone else might have another, better idea.

Comment: I tried using dynamic SQL (which is something new to me) and the error change to: 
" ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got. ".
I tried using : --> " create_backup := 'select /*insert*/ * from my_table where my_id = :x';
execute IMMEDIATE create_backup into v_omg using v_test; "

Comment: You don't need to actually *execute* that statement - just display it.

Comment: well that's the thing ... i want to display the result of that specific query. If i print the statement, it doesn't really do what i need it to do.